# Term for accessor/mutator method

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, terminology

I am a bit tired of using "accessor-slash-mutator" description for a methods that may work as both accessors and mutators.
Is there a single-word term for such methods in OOP terminology?

Comment: Can you give an example in two or more languages of such a method in use? From what I understand, you seem to be referring to some syntax or functionality like `person.age(5)` (setting) and `ageNextYear = person.age() + 1` (getting). I assume you are not talking about Python's *properties* (`person.age`, where `person.age = ...` implicitly can call a setter, and `person.age` can implicity call a getter), nor about Java's *fields* which are typically accessed via getter/setter methods that may be autogenerated.

Comment: Yep, I am talking about methods that combine getting/setting functionality, like in Perl: `package MyClass;
sub new {bless({MyAttr => 42}, shift())}
sub MutatorAccessor {
my $obj = shift();
 if (@_) {
 ($obj->{'MyAttr'}) = @_;
 } else {
 return $obj->{'MyAttr'};
 }
}` or in Javascript: `function MyClass () {
this.MyAttr = 42;
this.MutatorAccessor = function (val) {
  if (arguments.length) {
  this.MyAttr = val;
  } else {
  return this.MyAttr;
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Accessutator ? (padding)

Comment: That does not seem to be standard javascript? Is that standard perl?

Comment: As incorrect as it is, I and a lot of people use 'getter' or 'getter methods' since they usually contain the word 'get'. Plus in .Net systems, where properties have been introduced as a form of syntactic sugar, the terms 'getter' and 'setter' are quite commonplace.

Comment: Did you ever come up with an answer? For those asking before, this is a very common idiom in javascript. I usually use `function accessormutator(value) { if (!arguments.length) return this.value; this.value = value;} ` (which is basically the same as the example the OP posted) . It feels there should be a term to describe such methods.